# How to write native C++ in VS 2022, using Linux for build and test

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, cmake, msbuild

I need a native C++ app to make from scratch. It has to run on linux (CentOS). I want to use VS2022 to write and test. I have Hyper-V VM with CentOS.

I tried to google a solution but there are only posts for using WSL.

Can someone please describe steps to connect VS to Linux VM instead of WSL so I can build and run the app on the VM.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/connect-to-your-remote-linux-computer?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article describes the process: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/

- add workload to the VS using VS Installer (Linux and embedded..)
- create project of correct type
- add SSH credentials in the project Properties (also can be added/removed/edited in Tools-Options-Cross Platform)